# Unwanted Border CSS (Chrome & Firefox)

Tags: css, margin, w3.css

I've had a real search through the existing questions here, and I've trawled Google for hours looking for a solution - but it seems this issue is quite specific.

In a nutshell, I have a fairly large table that contains multiple rows (a person on each line). There's a single column in each row, which I "split" into multiple DIVs using [W3.CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_layout.asp). (I use DIVs instead of additional TD's because the width of each DIV is will be different for each person - sort of like a Gantt chart style workforce management system).

The problem I'm having is that specifically in Chrome (not IE or Edge), I'm experiencing this random margin:

- [The page in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6f42.png)
- [The page in IE/Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZE4S.png)

I've used Chrome's Dev Tools to try to figure it out, and you can see from [this snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAU2U.png) that the whole row (whether it's the TD or one or the DIVs - I don't know) seems to be 30px high, yet the content is only [24px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Fgn.png).

It's driving me nuts, so I would really appreciate any support - even if it's to tell me I'm missing something obvious! Coding wise, I'm only just past the point of beginner, so I'm open minded that I'm not doing this right!

```
<div class="w3-container" style="width: 100%; margin:auto; ">
<table id="php_siteid" style="width: 100%; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;"> 
  <tr>
<td style="border-bottom: 3px #FFFFFF solid; padding: 0px; " class="<?php print rowClassChange($i); ?>">
    <div style="width: 100%;" class="w3-cell-row">
        <div style="width: 100px; padding-left: 10px;" class="w3-cell w3-left-align">
            <div class="w3-cell-row" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="tooltip w3-cell" style="width: 100%;"><?php if (hasAccess("scheduler")) { ?><strong><span class="fakeLink" onclick="document.getElementById('id<?php print $agentLineDetails["agentid"]; ?>').style.display='block'" style="font-weight: bold;"><?php print $agentLineDetails["agentname"]; ?></span></strong><?php } else { include('inc/inc_agentsummary.php'); ?><strong><span class="fakeLink" onclick="document.getElementById('id_summary_<?php print $agentLineDetails["agentid"]; ?>').style.display='block'" style="font-weight: bold;"><?php print $agentLineDetails["agentname"]; ?></span></strong><?php } ?><span class="tooltiptext"><strong><?php print $agentLineDetails["agentname"] . "<BR>" . $shiftTime; ?></strong></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-cell w3-left-align w3-rest">
            <div class="w3-cell-row" style="width: 100%;">
                <div class="w3-cell w3-left-align" style="background-color: transparent; width: 10%;"></div>
                <div class="w3-cell w3-left-align" style="background-color: #7CBD85; width: 20%;"></div>
                <div class="w3-cell w3-left-align" style="background-color: #a32985; width: 15%; color: white; padding-left: 10px; border-left: 1px #E7E7E7 solid; border-right: 1px #E7E7E7 solid;">MFMT</div>
                <div class="w3-cell w3-left-align" style="background-color: #7CBD85; width: 20%;"></div>
                <div class="w3-cell w3-left-align" style="background-color: transparent; width: 35%;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if (hasAccess("scheduler")) { include('inc/inc_agentweeklinks.php'); }  ?>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Thanks so much in advance - happy to provide more information/code if needed :)

Jamie

Comment: are the `display` property `inline-block`? if yes you can try to add `vertical-align: middle (or something else)` to css or style

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve]. That includes the static HTML needed to reproduce this issue (plus what else might be nedded, stylesheets etc.), because no one here has your server-side setup available, so we can’t be sure what exactly your PHP code will produce to begin with. Discussion of client-side problem = post client-side code.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that the "rowClassChange" PHP function only changed the background colour. There's nothing else within those CSS classes (like margins etc.)

Comment: Still. We expect you to show code that we can actually use and run to test. This code should also show your issue. So, please provide the HTML and CSS where we can see the issue.

Comment: use any css reset like normalize.css and give a try

Comment: Thanks, all - I've added the site link now. Doh! 
ChandraShekhar - thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work unfortunately. 
YongQuan - the w3-cell-row and w3-cell classes use display: table, and already have a vertical-align: top property. I've tried overriding with middle, but it hasn't worked either, sadly. Thank you, though.

Comment: `.w3-cell-row::before { display: table }` disabling this in dev tools seems to render the same as IE/Edge.

Comment: Don't assume that one browser is rendering things "correctly" over another just because it displays it how you would like, especially when using frameworks. Have you tried Firefox, or any other browsers?

Comment: @phuzi - great shout. Firefox shows it the same as Chrome - thanks for the suggestion. Absolutely agree that IE showing it as I want it doesn't mean it's right - I'm more concerned that Chrome (which I prefer for everything) shows it incorrectly, so the code isn't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about each browser default behavior. Chrome dose not set any value for `vertical-align`. Just define that property (In your case dosen't matter which value you will assign) to `.w3-cell` class which has that specific `display` value:

```
.w3-cell{
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this has resolved it in Chrome and Firefox, and now it displays consistently across all browsers. And I've learned something new! Massive kudos to you, thanks Soheil.